# DB2 database on Docker could not be accessed from Spring Boot application and SQL Developer

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, hibernate, db2

I'm trying to access my DB2 database which is running  on a docker container but I'm always getting this error message from Spring Boot application:

`com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.19.26] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream, or socket output stream. Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1). Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001`

My application.properties file looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.username=db2inst1
spring.datasource.password=dbpass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyHbmImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect
```

How can this problem be solved? I've been searching in internet but did not find a clear solution for this problem as it can't be a firewall problemand  the db2comm is correctly configured as tcpip.

Comment: missing information. Please edit your question (do not use comments) to add the full command line you used for the `docker run...`,  and add the host operating-system details, and what firewall is active, and how you configured that firewall to allow IP traffic for the selected port.

Comment: Can you perform a `telnet host port` to the IP and port? Likely, it will fail because of firewalling...

Comment: What do you mean that I have to configure the Firewall? The container is running locally actually.

Comment: @data_henrik the telnet did not fail. The docker image is running at localhost so there should be no firewall problems

Comment: What was the telnet command? Is the IP / PORT the same as in your connect string? What is your connection string? The Docker container usually shielded from accessing the host system, it is "firewalled".

Comment: @data_henrik how could remove that firewall from my docker container?

Comment: There are some open questions in the comments which you have not answered. Add details to your question above.

Comment: Hey @data_henrik the telnet command is : telnet localhost 50000

Comment: I got the docker container from the official docker website https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2
I went inside the container trying to disable the firewall iptables but I can't find it and the command iptables cannot be executed inside the container. Hiw can the container be shielded otherwise?

Comment: There is still information missing, add it to the question: The command how you started the container. Did you run the telnet from outside the container, just to be sure? Add it to the question.